# In java, how can i search String array in another String array?

Tags: java, arrays, search

I have two different String array.

```
String[] str1={(ABC),(CDE),(DEF),(FGE),(ERT)};

String[] str2={(ABC),(FGE)};
```

I wanna know is str1 have str2's all members?How can i search str2 in str1?

Comment: Did you mean `"ABC"`, instead of `(ABC)`, etc.?

Answer (score 6):

```
Arrays.asList(str1).containsAll(Arrays.asList(str2));
```

Answer (score 2):

Create one Set object for each of your arrays containing the elements of the array. Then use the Set class's containsAll method to check that the one Set contains all of the elements from the other Set.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html

Comment: You need only a `Set` (i.e. a structure with fast `contains` check) for the bigger array, for the other one a `List` (like `Arrays.asList()`) works too without loosing efficiency. (And it should be a HashSet or TreeSet. Most efficiently if you can reuse it instead of recreating it for each search.)

Comment: @Paŭlo Ebermann Good addition (the comment about HashSet). Although a Set may only have benefits for larger arrays, I think that it is overall a better solution than mportiz08 posted, since the choice of Set or List really doesn't matter for smaller input.

Answer (score 1):

You could search each and every element of str2 in str1. Or, more efficiently: sort str1, and use binary search.