# In java, search String array in String array

Tags: java, arrays, search

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In java, how can i search String array in another String array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5825641/in-java-how-can-i-search-string-array-in-another-string-array)

I have two String array

```
String[] str1={("123"),("abc"),("cde"),("456"),("def")};

String[] str2={("gth"),("abc")};
```

I wanna know is str1 have str2's at least one member?

Comment: no it's not same i wanna 'at least'. In this tittle 'all'.

Comment: Hi, use the retainAll() method with the help of sets. Check the Set Interface Documentation at http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/set.html